# How is Yi, as in Yi Dynasty, spelled in Hangul?

Tags: hangul, names

How is `Yi`, as in *Yi Dynasty*, spelled in Hangul?

Comment: this question is a better fit for [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41465/korean-language)

Answer (score 1):

It's '이'. This is one of the Hangul representations of the Hanja character 
[**李**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9D%8E). This is the same character as the modern name anglicised as 'Lee'.

Comment: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/468/why-is-the-korean-name-이-often-romanised-as-lee may also be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the Joseon Dynasty, 조선 왕조 is the most common name. You can also say 이씨 조선 or 이씨 왕조, in contrast to the 김씨 조선 which is north korea.